# Where does Winetricks download its MS dll files, fonts, etc. from?

Tags: downloads, winetricks

Not the best at understanding code, and I did try digging through the [Winetricks Repository](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks) already, but my question is where and how does winetricks get the Microsoft files from?

Are they downloaded from Microsoft's servers themselves or are they extracted from a installed version of windows and placed in an accessible server not owned by MS?